# Whole-Stage Code Generation in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I heard about `Whole-Stage Code Generation` for sql to optimize queries.
through [p539-neumann.pdf](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol4/p539-neumann.pdf) & [sparksql-sql-codegen-is-not-giving-any-improvemnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103133/sparksql-sql-codegen-is-not-giving-any-improvemnt)

But unfortunately no one gave answer to above question.

Curious to know about what are the scenarios to use this feature of Spark 2.0. But didn't get proper use-case after googling.

Whenever we are using sql, can we use this feature? if so, any proper use case to see this working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you are using Spark 2.0, code generation is enabled by default.  This allows for most DataFrame queries you are able to take advantage of the performance improvements.  There are some potential exceptions such as using Python UDFs that may slow things down.

Code generation is one of the primary components of the Spark SQL engine's Catalyst Optimizer.  In brief, the Catalyst Optimizer engine does the following:
(1) analyzing a logical plan to resolve references, 
(2) logical plan optimization
(3) physical planning, and 
(4) code generation

[image]

A great reference to all of this are the blog posts

- [Deep Dive into Spark SQL’s Catalyst
  Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html)
- [Apache Spark as a Compiler: Joining a Billion Rows per Second on a
  Laptop](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/23/apache-spark-as-a-compiler-joining-a-billion-rows-per-second-on-a-laptop.html)

HTH!

Comment: Many Thanks! So there is nothing explicit we need to do. It was feature by default in Spark 2.0. isn't it? if so, I was just wondering, why user is not able to feel difference with his sql query ? anything he needs to improve his query ?

Comment: Ahh for that it would require a little digging - what version of Spark, why HiveContext, and ultimately debugging the query.  HTH!

Comment: yes.  hiveContext is not available in spark 2.0. seems like he is using lower version of spark. thats the thing

Comment: Due to the timing of the question, yes it could be Apache Spark 1.6 or earlier which may be in play.

Comment: Physical planning and code generation are not part of catalyst framework. code generation is done at runtime in RDD#compute to faster task calculation

Comment: Also, code generation would be effective when the compute is more of CPU bound. If the computation was IO bound, there wouldn't be significant improvements.

Comment: @DennyLee can you give some context of why python UDFs are not so fit for the whole stage code generation?